# Highcharts Pie chart how to reduce space between chart and legend caused by plot width

Tags: javascript, highcharts, pie-chart

Is there a way to reduce the white space between the chart and the legend, when the legend is positioned to the right of the chart and its layout is set to vertical?
It seems like the problem is caused by the width of the plot area, which becomes unnecessarily big in pie charts since the chart is always going to be a circle. 
The chart's width and height cannot be fixed to allow for responsiveness.

https://jsfiddle.net/rredondo/gdh86chg/

The chart options are:

```
{
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    plotBorderWidth: 1,
    plotBorderColor: '#3F4044',
    borderColor: '#AAAAAA',
    borderWidth: 2
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Incidents',
    data: [{
      name: "Critical",
      y: 1,
      color: "#FF0000"
    }, {
      name: "Severe",
      y: 8,
      color: "#F57622"
    }, {
      name: "Major",
      y: 13,
      color: "#F0A401"
    }, {
      name: "Minor",
      y: 25,
      color: "#F0C801"
    }, {
      name: "Information",
      y: 30,
      color: "#4AB6FF"
    }],
    size: '80%',
    innerSize: '60%',
    showInLegend: true,
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
    }
  }],
  legend: {
    layout: "vertical",
    align: "right",
    verticalAlign: "middle",
  }
}
```

Comment: So you would like to achieve something similar to this chart? https://jsfiddle.net/gdh86chg/6/

Comment: At first glance yes, the problem is that when you increase the size of the chart container, the space between the legend and the actual chart also increases.

Comment: So you should be able to use attr() for moving your legend on chart load and redraw: https://jsfiddle.net/gdh86chg/10/

Comment: This is it, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have mentioned in my comment, you should be able to move your legend on chart load and redraw using attr():

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.redraw
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Element.attr

```
    // Create the chart
var updateLegend = function(chart) {
  var center = chart.series[0].center;
  console.log(chart.legend)
  chart.legend.group.attr({
    translateX: center[0] + center[2] / 2
  });
}
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    plotBorderColor: '#3F4044',
    borderColor: '#AAAAAA',
    borderWidth: 2,
    marginRight: 0,
    marginLeft: 0,
    events: {
      load: function() {
        updateLegend(this)
      },
      redraw: function() {
        updateLegend(this);
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Incidents',
    data: [{
      name: "Critical",
      y: 1,
      color: "#FF0000"
    }, {
      name: "Severe",
      y: 8,
      color: "#F57622"
    }, {
      name: "Major",
      y: 13,
      color: "#F0A401"
    }, {
      name: "Minor",
      y: 25,
      color: "#F0C801"
    }, {
      name: "Information",
      y: 30,
      color: "#4AB6FF"
    }],
    size: '80%',
    innerSize: '60%',
    showInLegend: true,
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
    }
  }],
  legend: {
    layout: "vertical",
    align: "right",
    verticalAlign: "middle",
  }
});
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/gdh86chg/11/

Comment: I would also add http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Element.attr to your answer. Just by looking at the API, it's not very clear which attributes are supported, so the solution was not obvious to me. Thanks!

Comment: Also, the property of the legend, x: -50, is not needed anymore.